# nodejs exec fails with sighup signal

Tags: node.js

I am facing error while creating a child_process via exec in nodejs.
It was working fine under 0.12.x node version, only change is nodejs upgrade to 6.11.3.This error occurs 2 out of 10 times not able to find the reason and solution. Thanks in advance

Code details:

```
   var exec = require('child_process').exec;
   cmd = 'sh /home/ec2-user/bin/lldn start';
   exec(cmd,{ shell: '/bin/bash'},
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            deferred.reject({
                stdout: stdout,
                stderr: stderr,
                error: error,
                cmd: cmd
            });
        } else {
            deferred.resolve({
                stdout: stdout,
                stderr: stderr,
                error: error,
                cmd: cmd
            });
        }
    });
```

Error details:

```
  msg="{ Error: Command failed: sh /home/ec2-
user/logu/datanode/bin/lldn start

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:198:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:230:5)
 killed: false,
code: null,
 signal: 'SIGHUP',
cmd: 'sh /home/ec2-user/logu/datanode/bin/lldn start' }"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a different command and after some digging I realized that `exec` is hiding the proper error.

I was able to show the real error adding a logger in the following place:

```
function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  // Not all three vars are needed, but better to show more
  console.log(error, stdout, stderr);
  if (error) {
    deferred.reject({
```

I know it's not the solution to your specific issue but I hope this helps.